# open hyperlink in new browser tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendoGrid with hyperlink column in it. The desired behavior is when I click on that column item it opens up a new browser tab and opens the document. 
I got the following working:

```
 columns: [
                {
                    selectable: true,
                    width: "10px",
                    headerTemplate: ' '
                },
                {
                    title: "ID",
                    field: "ProposalId",     
                    template: kendo.template("<a href='http://testapp.com/RateSheet?Id=${ProposalId}' onclick='window.open(this.href);return false;'>#= ProposalId # </a>")
}
```

But when I am trying to insert a dynamic url, I get an error: **SCRIPT1006: Expected ')'**

This is what I have to dynamically insert the url:

```
 template: kendo.template("<a href='" + @Model.SHEET_URL + "${ProposalId}' onclick='window.open(this.href);return false;'>#= PriceDealProposalId # </a>")
```

Value of SHEET_URL in the model is:

```
 this.SHEET_URL = "http://testapp.com/RateSheet?ProposalId=";
```

Comment: why not just add `target="_blank"` and there would be no need for JavaScript

Comment: definetly x,y problem. not need to do `window.open(this.href)` etc... just use target="blank" as epascarello said.